# Microsoft office Excel is waiting for another process to complete an OLE action

Tags: c#, excel

When trying to use an add-in I created in excel using `.net` I get this error:

> Microsoft office Excel is waiting for another process to complete an OLE action.

This crashes the application itself.

Please help!

Comment: -1 There is barely any information to go on here. It may, or may not be your add-in.

Answer (score 1):

Run Excel under WinDbg. Use this article to setup your (public) symbols: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311503
When the crash happen, you'll at least see what thread your crash happens on and what is actually causing it.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem. The errors occurs randomly, at first glance.
Then I found out that the file was on a synced cloud folder. Refreshing the file (which happens automatically on the distant folder), corrupted the file.
I solved the problem by relocating the necessary files to a local folder. Run the macro and then upload again. 
Macro runs like a charm now.